# composer-php can't use openssl via file_get_contents function

Tags: php, curl, openssl, composer-php

I'm using php version 5.4.7 with `openssl` enabled( i checked this with extension_loaded function ). The thing is when i want to issue any command with composer like `self-update`, `install`, `update` i'm getting this error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                   
The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto                                                                                         
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

for installing composer and using `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` i'm getting this error :

```
Download failed: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation failed
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

When i checked file_get_contents function with `https://google.com` or `https://facebook.com` there wasn't any error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you please call `php -i` and double-check that the command line version of PHP has all the needed extensions (the command is the equivalent of calling `phpinfo()` in a script). Your reported errors might come from a difference in configurations between the webserver PHP and the command line PHP.

Comment: Thanks for answering i checked with command line and there was an `openssl` extension in the list.As i said i checked other urls from command line like `https://google.com` and `https://facebook.com` and there was no problem.

Comment: Thanks for checking - I then must declare I am out of ideas of what went wrong in your case.